# How can I cross between two tables in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have two tables, one named "papers" with a column "titles" and one named "keywords" with a column "keyword". I need to cross each title from the titles column with each keyword from the keywords column in order to then check if each title contains a keyword. I was given an example of crossing between two tables as:

```
crossing(tibble(x = 1:3), tibble(y = letters[1:3]))
```

so I tried:

```
crossing(tibble(x = keywords), tibble(y = papers$title[keywords]))
```

but I am receiving an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without the `papers$title` or `keywords` or the error, it is difficult to give any insights

Comment: you misunderstood the function crossing, it's used to generate all possible combinations between the two data. what you need is something more complicated